# Chef/OpsWorks: instance failing on dokku deploy

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks, dokku, berkshelf

Was working fine until today. Getting an error with a dokku deployment script in OpsWorks Chef 11.10:

`Error executing action 'run' on resource 'ruby_block[git push --force dokku@localhost:api.website.com deploy:master]'`

Full Error Trace:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_block[git push --force dokku@localhost:api.website.com deploy:master]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of git push --force dokku@localhost:api.website.com deploy:master ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: warning: unable to access '/root/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
remote: -----> Setting config vars[K
remote:        GIT_REV: HASHKEY [K
remote: api.website.com is currently being deployed. Exiting...[K
To dokku@localhost:api.website.com
! [remote rejected] deploy -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@localhost:api.website.com'
---- End output of git push --force dokku@localhost:api.website.com deploy:master ----
Ran git push --force dokku@localhost:api.website.com deploy:master returned 1
```

I've checked to make sure no 3rd party cookbooks were updated recently, etc. Anyone know what the issue might be? Or where to start looking?

Comment: Your error is permission denied to your git attributes (`/root/.config/git/attributes`), did the perms change on that file?

Comment: That error has been there for a long time (even when the deployment worked), I can't find that file/path anywhere on the actual instance - would it be somewhere else?

Comment: Does pushing to Dokku work manually (i.e. not through Chef)?

Comment: @coderanger nope, getting this error with manual push to Dokku: -----> Unable to select a buildpack , none of the SO answers have worked for that fix so far

Comment: Update: I set BUILDPACK_URL: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-emberjs, which removes the `unable to select a buildpack` but now failing with ` [remote rejected] deploy -> master (pre-receive hook declined)` with no further info